# Difference between checking the value of an object's property and checking if a property is in an object

Tags: javascript

While checking if there is a value for a property in an object, I was using `if(prop in object) return object[prop] else object[prop] = x` (*x is some variable outside of this question*) to determine if an entry has been made into the object. Should I just use `if(object[prop])`, because if the property doesn't exist, it will return undefined? Is using the `in` operator just as fast? The only pitfall caused by changing to check the value is if the value if `null`, `0`, `-0`, `false`, or `NaN`, it will return false when I want a falsy value, is there anything else I should watch out for?

Comment: The value could also be `undefined`. If you're sure that, if it'll exist, it'll be truthy, feel free to use `if(object[prop])`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: @Phil Oh, I totally forgot about that, is there any difference between the `in` operator and `hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @Red yes http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html

Comment: Okay, immediate I found the prototype chain difference

Comment: @Phil It appears hasOwn... is exactly what I need, I tried this and `in` failed `let test =
{
    [[1,2,3]]:5
}

test.hasOwnProperty([1,2,3])`

Comment: Well, you've got some implicit array-to-string conversion going on there which is rarely a good thing